Does ATP drive cellular work solely from energy release during hydrolysis, or is additional work done by repulsion of ADP and inorganic phosphate?
After ADP and Pi are no longer bound to each other but still bound to an enzyme, do they repel each other? If so, does that contribute to the work that ATP hydrolysis can do?

I have written my answer in more detail. I suggest a better title for your question. It is up to you whether you adopt it or not. If you do I will modify my answer accordingly.

Definition of Terms: Energy and Work in metabolic interconversions
The title of this question uses the terms “cellular work” and “energy release” in a very general sense, so I think it is important to start be establishing what ‘energy’ and ‘work’ mean in relation to biochemical reactions, in order to relate them more rigorously to the role of ATP in metabolism.
Energy. Biochemists — and  biolochemical texts — consider metabolism energy in thermodynamic terms, specifically in relation to what is known as the Gibbs Free Energy (G). This is not as it applies to individual compounds (which is difficult or impossible to measure) but in relation to the overall change in this Gibbs Free Energy (ΔG) that occurs during a particular chemical reaction, considering both the reactants and products. The basic precept is that if ΔG is negative, the reaction proceeds ‘spontaneously’.  I would emphasize that this is a ‘black box approach’: we do not need to know, and do not consider how the change is accomplished in molecular terms — that is the realm of reaction mechanism and kinetics, not thermodynamic energy.
Work. A general definition of energy I remember from school physics is “the ability to do work”, and searching the internet I find this is still used (with ‘capacity’ replacing ‘ability’).  Elsewhere I find it defined as “… the energy transferred from one thermodynamic system into another thermodynamic system”. This is most easily envisaged in terms of mechanical work, but, although ATP is involved in this in biological systems, the question is about the ‘work’ done in facilitating a non-spontaneous reaction — one with a positive ΔG. (The difference of this from mechanical or electrical work means that the term ‘work’ is quite infrequently used in biochemical texts in relation to metabolic reactions.)
Restating the question
The phrases “drive cellular work” and “energy release” in the title do not fit well with the definitions above. I suggest it would be best to rephrase the question as:

“Does ATP perform cellular work solely from the free energy change
during its hydrolysis, or is additional energy obtained by repulsion
between ADP and inorganic phosphate?”

Thermodynamics of ATP hydrolysis in coupled biochemical reactions
Two things are required for ATP hydrolysis to facilitate a non-spontaneous chemical reaction:

The unsigned value of the negative ΔG for the reaction of ATP hydrolysis must be greater than that of the positive ΔG for the reaction that is being enabled. i.e. The overall ΔG for the two reactions considered together must be negative.
There must be a mechanism to couple the reactions, i.e. to ensure that the energy of the phosphoanhydride bond is used to form bonds in other reactants and not lost as heat.

An enzymic reaction mechanism will involve a pathway that differs from an uncatalyzed reaction and will have intermediates with different energy states (e.g. below), but the details of this have no relevance to the thermodynamics of the overall change involved. This depends solely on the overall free energies of the reactants and the products, and the change in their combined reaction.

[Example of the energy changes during a simple unimolecular enzymic reaction]
Answer to the question
From this it can be seen that the answer to the question of whether additional energy is obtained by repulsion between ADP and inorganic phosphate is

“No, The energy driving the reaction arises solely from the free
energy change during hydrolysis”.

Any repulsion of ADP and Pi on the enzyme has no bearing on the energetics. If such repulsion does, in fact, occur, its influence would be on the release of the reaction intermediates at some point along the reaction pathway of the type illustrated. The energy changes along the pathway have no effect on the overall free energy change.
Coda: Does direct hydrolysis of ATP to inorganic phosphate actually occur in metabolism?
The assumption in the question is that in coupled metabolic reactions involving ATP, inorganic phosphate is released directly by hydrolysis of the phosphoanhydride bond. This is generally not the case, as multi-step reactions normally occur in which the phosphoryl group is transferred to another participant, ‘activating it’ for the energetically unfavourable reaction. (Or the ADP (or AMP) moiety is transferred to another compound and phosphate released.) I have addressed this point in more detail in an answer to a related question from the poster.
Bibliography
A good place to read about biochemical thermodynamics is in Biochemistry, by Berg et al. It should be possible to pick up an older edition cheaply on eBay etc. Although not as good in my opinion, there is a freely accessible chapter in a book on NCBI Bookshelf in which the section on Metabolic Energy explains this generally accepted approach to biochemical thermodynamics.

To perhaps clarify for a lay audience, work done by repulsion of the hydrolysis reaction products is still work done by the reaction.

@timeskull Not sure what you mean but my expanded revised answer tries to deal with this in terms of the reaction pathway. I'm also not sure that a layman can deal with thermodynamics…

I do not mention the term "energy charge" in my answer, so whether or not it is controversial seems irrelevant to this answer. I am following the views expressed almost universally that the Gibbs free energy change in any reaction determines its spontaneous direction, and that it is possible to for a reaction with a negative free energy change to be coupled to one with a numerical smaller positive free energy change. Are these views controversial?

I beg to differ. I think it is extremely relevant as it addresses the basic misunderstanding of the poster. If I spend several hours on an answer I make sure it is relevant to the question asked. You can see this in my highlighting the crux of the question in precise terms, and flagging my answer.

"This is most easily envisaged in terms of mechanical work, but, although ATP is involved in this in biological systems, the question is about the ‘work’ done in facilitating a non-spontaneous reaction — one with a positive ΔG." Unlike my other question, this question was meant to be about mechanical work. I'm not sure if that changes much to your answer? I would like to keep the answer you've posted in existence; would it be easiest for me to ask another question about mechanical work and edit this one to be explicitly about non-spontaneous reaction stuff?

@elijahwhipple — I strongly agree with your proposal. I know less about coupling to mechanical work, and have started (very slowly) reading what is know in different examples. I happened to be reading an old question on Physics SE which asked about ATP activation energy in relation to mechanical work, and didn't have very satisfactory answers, but I decided not to answer myself until I had studied the topic a little more.
